# JBoss Portal tab customization

Tags: jboss-portal

I am using JBoss Portal 2.7.2. My problem is when I click on any of the tabs (say tab1) and navigate into other views under the same tab and click on another tab (say tab2). Now when I click on previous tab (i.e., tab1) I move to the page that I have last accessed in that tab, which I don't want to. Instead I want to display the home page of that tab.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using generic portlet then you can solve this problem by

1. store your action in **session** and
2. after the completion of action remove your session

Comment: I've edited out the last part of your answer, since it really should be in a question and not an answer.